# cropping a bitmap without creating another bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, crop

I need to crop a fullscreen, background Bitmap that is pretty big (10mb), and sometimes I just can't afford allocating another bitmap for it.

I wonder if there's a way to crop a bitmap in itself, without creating another bitmap in the process.

```
    Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, x, y, w, h)
```

This function is perfect, but the problem is, it allocates the memory.

I just need to crop 25% height.

Comment: You may be better served creating your own `View` that only renders the part you want.

Comment: why? If I crop it, I will save 4mb for the application heap, I don't think it's a bad idea.

Comment: It's not, except that you said you don't have the memory to do it. Another possibility, if the background is a drawable resource, is to use a `ClipDrawable` to represent the clip operation.

Comment: I don't have problems to clip the bitmap, I can do it in a variety of ways, as you say. My problem is, that a 30% of the bitmap is NEVER going to be drawn and it's sitting there, eating precious heap. I'd just like to create a cropped version without allocating 15mb for it in the process. I thought it was going to be very easy to do!

Comment: This is one of the reason why some people go with tiling approaches, so you only load in the tiles for your background that you will need.

Comment: Yes, tiling is a gorgeous solution, but doesn't fit very well my use case. It would be too much just for my only problem, that is cropping a 30% in height.